# How to run shell script after every startup to check if another podcast has been uploaded?

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to be able to, when another podcast is posted, to scrape the url, put it into my text doc and download the mp3 files I don't already have into one folder containing all the episodes. I am already able to download the mp3's using my current list in the text file.

Below is my shell script to run each line in the text file pointed to:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/home/gome/Downloads/darknetdiaries.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
  $line
done < "$input"
```

Below is my shell script to make a directory if there is not currently one or and to fill it with the input:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Script executed from: ${PWD}"
echo "Where do you want to save files?  (Enter a directory name)   "
read dirname

if [[ ! -d "$dirname" ]]
then
    if [[ -L "$dirname" ]]
then
    echo "File doesn't exist. Creating now"
    mkdir -p -- "./$dirname"
    echo "File created"
    else
        echo "File exists"
    fi
fi

var1="VALUE 1"


cat > ${PWD}/$dirname/file1 << EOF1
do some commands on "$var1"
and/or "$var2"
EOF1
```

I am currently getting an error that looks like this:
[image: When I run my shell script]

When both above scripts are combined, I get this:
Note: I made a copy of the original text file for testing purposes only! Shortened the list to only pull one mp3 file only to test functionality. ***The code says the file exists but it does not?***
[image]

Both combined:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/home/gome/Downloads/darknetdiaries (copy).txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
  $line
done < "$input"

echo "Script executed from: ${PWD}"
echo "Where do you want to save files?  (Enter a directory name)   "
read dirname

    if [[ ! -d "$dirname" ]]
    then
        if [[ -L "$dirname" ]]
    then
        echo "File doesn't exist. Creating now"
        mkdir -p -- "./$dirname"
        echo "File created"
        else
            echo "File exists"
        fi
    fi
$line >> ${PWD}/$dirname/file1 << EOF
EOF
```

Below is my current text file only containing unique links to unique episodes:

```
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep10-wiretap-mishap.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep11-buyout.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep12-cryptowars.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep13-carna.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep14-opjustina2.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep15-illtill.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep16-eijah.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep17-finn.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep18-jackpot.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep19-aurora.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep1-pbx-hacking.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep20-mobman.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep21-black-duck-eggs.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep22-ministories1.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep23-levin.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep24-bayonet.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep25-alberto.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep26-irs.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep27-chartbreakers.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep28-unit8200.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep29-stuxnet.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep2-vtech.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep30-shamoon.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep31-hackergiraffe.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep32-thecarder.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep33-rockyou.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep34-foryoureyesonly.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep35-carbanak.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep36-jeremyfrommarketing.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep37-lvs.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep38-dark-caracal.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep39-3alarmlampscooter.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep3-diginotar.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep40-no-parking.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep41-just-visiting.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep42-ministories-vol2.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep43-ppp.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep44-zain.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep45-xbox1.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep46-xbox2.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep47-projectraven.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep48-opsocialist.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep49-elliot.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep4-talktalk.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep50-glowing-symphony.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep51-indopak-conflict.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep52-magecart.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep53-shadowbrokers.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep54-notpetya.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep55-noirnet.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep56-jordan.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep57-ms08067.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep58-oxymonster.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep59-courthouse.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep5-asus.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep60-dawgyg.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep61-samy.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep62-cam.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep63-w0rmer.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep64-shadowphones.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep65-psyop.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep66-freakyclown.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep67-the-big-house.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep68-triton.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep69-humanhacker.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep6-jaysonstreet.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep70-ghostexodus.mp3  
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep71-fdff.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep72-bangladeshbank.mp3   
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep73-wannacry.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep74-mikko.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep75-compromised-comms.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep76-knavesout.mp3    
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep77-olympicdestroyer.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep7-manfred-part1.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep8-manfred-part2.mp3 
wget  https://darknetdiaries.com/podcasts/darknet-diaries-ep9-mtgox.mp3
```

Comment: IMHO, all the code you have posted doesn't address your new requirment, *"when another podcast is posted, to scrape the url, put it into my text doc and download the mp3 files..."*. So how are you attempting to scrape the url, append? it to your text doc? How are you avoiding downloading files you have already retrieved? I think this could be reformulated as *"how do I get any new episodes"*. It's too bad the `darknetdiaries` didn't bother to number the episodes with padded zeros,((`ep005` maybe) which would allow a much easier tracking system. ....

Comment: Please edit your Q to show your best attempt to solve these issues. If there are any other pods you wish to manage in the same way, I would consider storing those lists in a small database (mySQL?). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Cron** to run your script at startup of the system.

```
crontab -e
```

then add

```
@reboot /your/script/path.sh
```